# I cannot update the unit price field on OpportunityLineItem

Tags: field-update, opportunity-lineitem

I am trying to update the UnitPrice on the OpportunityLineItem object; however, it does not update the field, my code is as follows:

```
Id oliId = '00k1w000006SpWE';

OpportunityLineItem oli = [SELECT Id, UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id = :oliId];
oli.UnitPrice = 100.01;

update oli;
```

I am expecting the unit price to be 100.01; however, it shows the old value.

I checked the [SOAP API for OpportunityLineItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm), and it stays that UnitPrice field can be updated. I also disabled the triggers and workflow rules.

Comment: how are you running this code? Within a trigger, anonymous apex, through a soap call, etc.

Comment: anonymous apex.

Comment: What do the values of this OpportunityLineItem look like? In particular, does it already have values for quantity, discount, and TotalPrice?

Comment: the current state of this record is {"UnitPrice": 252.0, "TotalPrice":  252.0,  "Quantity": 1.0, "Discount":  }

Comment: Are you getting any error message when executing your anon apex? Salesforce should be complaining that UnitPrice and TotalPrice cannot both be set (or maybe that only happens if you query both fields).

Comment: For what it's worth, your code works in my sandbox and reflects the new price in the UI. Does the opp product show yourself as "last modified by" after running the anonymous code?

Comment: Hi @DerekF, no exception, not even when querying both, UnitPrice and TotalPrice. Actually, last year we also update this field, and it worked.

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves, I see myself as last modified after I run the code.

Comment: DO you have any app exchange package trigger on Opportunity Line Item? Can you make the debug level to finest and see whats going on?

Comment: There's multiple avenues for fields to update after a DML is called to the record. You're going to have to check triggers, workflow rules, process builder etc. These all will fire after you execute your code.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I checked, and I do not have any app exchange package trigger on Opportunity Line Item

Comment: @DrewKennedy I checked the logs, there is no trigger or whatsoever running between the DML update. I disabled all. Same Issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to update the UnitPrice by first removing all its related OpportunityLineItemSchedule records, the code as follows:

```
Id oliId = '00k1w000006SpWE';

List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> olisList = [SELECT Id FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule WHERE OpportunityLineItemId = :oliId];

delete olisList;

OpportunityLineItem oli = [SELECT Id, UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id = :oliId];
oli.UnitPrice = 100.01;

update oli;
```

Now I can update the UnitPrice. I thought I got an issue with some triggers or further checks, for example, workflow rules or process builders; however, after I disabled all of them, I still got the same issue.

Comment: The document tells about the effect of OpportunityLineItemSchedule on OLI, but does not clarify if you won't be able to change the unit price. Weird.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitemschedule.htm